# An algorithm to find all distinct sums from a list of numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, combinations, permutation

Sample input:

```
4 6 4 3 2 2 1 1
```

First number = A total, T (T < 1000)

Second number = Number of numbers, S (S <= 12)

Following S numbers = The values of the numbers (each value < 100). (Repetition can happen, input is given in non-increasing order)

My job is to find all "distinct sums" using numbers from the list that add up to T.

So, sample output for that input would be:

```
4
3+1
2+2
2+1+1
```

My thought was to go through the list 1 by 1, and find all combinations of a number with a different number, up to the size of the list of numbers - # of numbers already evaluated. You create a List out of each combination and add the List to a HashSet of Lists (HashSet to prevent duplicates).

So, you'd check for all 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6-sized combinations to go with 4 first
Then all 1, 2, 3, 4, 5-sized combinations to go with 3, ignoring 4
Then all 1, 2, 3, 4-sized combinations to go with 2, ignoring 4 and 3

etc.

1. I'm not sure if this algorithm is actually efficient
2. I have a tough time both with implementing that algorithm. I can't wrap my head around how to loop the structure so as to get the desired combinations.

Comment: Recursion will work, provided that `S` is reasonably small. What are the constraints on `T`, `S`, and the values?

Comment: What are the constraints on T and S this is **really** important to choose the algorithm. Also if this is a question from a coding contest can you provide a link to validate our answers ?

Comment: The constraints are pretty small, T is < 1000, there will be no more than 12 integers, and all integers are less than 100.

Comment: In that case even a `O(2^n)` complexity is acceptable, it won't take more than a millisecond to a modern CPU to brute-force the result.

Answer (score 1):

You should try a recursive solution. Mainly you just have to work with the idea that for each number you can either include it in your sum or you can't. This means you're building the power set of your numbers and will result in a `O(2^N)` solution.

Briefly in pseudocode:

```
def get_all_sums(arr, target):

    result = []

    def helper(index, current_arr, current_sum):

        # once you've gone over the arr you can return. If all your numbers are positive
        # you can also return early if the current_sum > target
        if index == len(arr): return

        # solution found - add it to the result
        if current_sum == target: result.append(current_arr)

        # include the current index
        helper(index + 1, current_arr + [arr[index]], current_sum + arr[index])

        # don't include the current index
        helper(index + 1, current_arr, current_sum)

    helper(0, [], 0)

    # sort and hash to get rid of duplicates; return a set
    return {tuple(sorted(i) for i in result)}
```

Comment: Can you explain what current_arr is, and how you're utilizing the parameters for dfs?  As in, what does your dfs implementation look like?

Comment: @AndIAm sorry it should have been `helper` not `dfs`

Comment: It is not working ... do you have any correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found with simple recursion, which I will demonstrate using the example from the question.

At the first level of recursion, the problem to be solved is

```
target=4 count=6 allowed={4,3,2,2,1,1} chosen={}
```

The first level chooses each unique value in a loop and then makes a recursive call. So the recursive calls from the first level are

```
target=0 size=5 allowed={3,2,2,1,1} chosen={4}
target=1 size=4 allowed={2,2,1,1} chosen={3}
target=2 size=3 allowed={2,1,1} chosen={2}
target=3 size=1 allowed={1} chosen={1}
```

The key here is that the array of allowed values gets smaller at each level of recursion. Only those values that follow the chosen value may be used. So, for example, when the first level of recursion chooses the value 3, then only values smaller than 3 are allowed. In the case of duplicates, the first duplicate is chosen, and the allowed values are restricted to the remaining duplicates, and any smaller values.

---

At the second level of recursion when the parameters are

```
target=0 size=5 allowed={3,2,2,1,1} chosen={4}
```

This is the successful base case: `target` is 0. In this case **add {4} to the output list**, since that's a solution.

---

At the second level of recursion when the parameters are

```
target=1 size=4 allowed={2,2,1,1} chosen={3}
```

The code should skip the 2's since 2 is larger than the target. So the only recursive call is

```
target=0 size=1 allowed={1} chosen={3,1}
```

This again is the base case, so the third level of recursion will **add {3,1} to the output**.

---

At the second level of recursion when the parameters are

```
target=2 size=3 allowed={2,1,1} chosen={2}
```

there will be two recursive calls

```
target=0 size=2 allowed={1,1} chosen={2,2}
target=1 size=1 allowed={1} chosen={2,1}
```

The first of those is a base case so **add {2,2} to the output**. The other recursive call will eventually **add {2,1,1} to the output**.

---

At the second level of recursion when the parameters are

```
target=3 size=1 allowed={1} chosen={1}
```

there is one recursive call

```
target=2 size=0 allowed={} chosen={1,1}
```

This is the failed base case: `target` is non-zero and `size` is 0.

---

Note that when the problem is solved this way, only unique solutions are generated, so there is no need to remove duplicate solutions.

Also note that the maximum recursion depth is determined by `S`, so it's important that `S` be constrained to a reasonably small number (`S <= 12` qualifies as reasonably small).